# JavaScript function inside HTML display in browser

Tags: javascript, html, output

I have a problem regarding my JavaScript code. I'm trying to output the sum in the browser, but it doesn't work. I tried every way of displaying the message in JavaScript: `console.log()`, `document.write()`, `document.getElementById()`. None of this seems to work. My code looks okay, but it simply won't output anything. Can someone help me, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var sum = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ 
        if(i%3 === 0 || i%5 === 0)   
        {
           sum += i; 
        }
        console.log('The sum is' + " " +sum);
     }
   </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: press `f12` to open devtool and click on `console` tab

Comment: `console.log` outputs the broswer console (`f12`) not the DOM, also how have you tried with `document.write()` and `document.getElementById()` since those methods are different than doing a simple `console.log`

Comment: Yes,you're right!It's working as you said,but why is not the message inside console.log displayed in the browser?

Comment: Because the console and the DOM are two completely different things

Comment: I tried everything I could to display the sum in the browser.I even made a special button that would display the sum once it was clicked,nothing worked...

Comment: @ElizaMaria See my answer below... the 2nd snippet shows one way to display your output in the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine here.  I'm running IE11 and the sum displays in the console with no problem. See the snippet below; nothing has been changed.

Maybe you just need to open the dev console?  <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE/Edge, or **Settings > Developer Tools > Console** in Chrome (I think).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
      console.log('The sum is' + " " + sum);
    }
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

If you want to have your code output to the browser window, you could do something like this, where you add the result to the DOM:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='resultsDiv'>
    <h3>Results Here:</h3>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sum = 0;
    var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
      resultsDiv.innerHTML += 'The sum is' + " " + sum + "<br />";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!They were really helpful!:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you wrote that you want to display in the browser, I assume you mean the [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

First of all, you need a body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Sure, the Javascript can be inside the HEAD tag, but if you want anything to be displayed, it needs to be inside the BODY tag.

Second, console.log will print the result to the console, if you want to print the sum in the body, you should change the **"print"** part to something like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML = 'The sum is' + " " + sum;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = 'The sum is' + " " + sum;
```

Where **sum** will be an id attribute added to the *body tag*, also, the

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Goes inside the HEAD tag, and last but not least, you are executing the javascript right away and the DOM won't be necessarily loaded, I suggest you create a javascript function to be called **onload** as an attribute in the body tag.

So, a working implementation could be like this:

```js
function sum(){
  var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
      console.log('The sum is' + " " + sum);
    }
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = 'The sum is ' + sum
}
```

```html
<body id="sum" onload="sum()"></body>
```

The code will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sum(){

                var sum = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
                            sum += i;
                        }
                        console.log('The sum is' + " " + sum);
                    }
                //document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML = 'The sum is ' + sum
                document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = 'The sum is ' + sum
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="sum" onload="sum()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not teach people to put event handler on a tag - certainly not the body tag. Also if you make a snippet, make it run

Comment: Thank your for your comment, the snippet runs, at least for me, and just to learn a little bit more, why isn't recommended to put an event handler on a tag, in this case, the body tag?

Comment: Put it always at the closest static tag you can. 90% of the time the container that hosts the dynamic content. The higher up the DOM, the longer it takes to bubble up

Comment: Understood, Very logical argument, thank you very much, something new to learn.